# mysql select count resource id #10

Tags: sql, select

When I run the following code the echo returns resource id #10 instead of number, in my case 6.  Would appreciate any help!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`category_id`) FROM `products_has_product_category`
WHERE `category_id`=1");
        echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use function `mysql_fetch_object` or `mysql_fetch_row` to convert query result to data

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`category_id`) as count FROM `products_has_product_category`
WHERE `category_id`=1");

$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$count = $row->count;
echo $count;
```

see [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: @Farnabz Im not using PDO, but you definitely pointed my in the right direction.  I used $number = mysql_fetch_row($result) and then echo $number[0];.  Thank you again!!!